# How to check on Android if a file is open in write mode by another application

Tags: java, android

The Scenario:
A file is being downloaded from Internet .An application tries to read the same file , while it is being downloaded .How can that application check that this file is already opened in write mode.

Platform:
Android

Comment: The Question is not about when the writer finished, But to be aware that the file is being written to

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the file is being written to by polling the modification date.  Once the file hasn't been modified for a while you might assume it has downloaded.  Otherwise, there is no reliable way to do this without reading the file to see if it is complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , There could be cases where writer modifies the file after longer time interval (lets say some logging system is the writer) , So in that case this check may fail.

Comment: In the case of a logger it might not be possible to tell when ti has finished.

Comment: May be for this scenario  file.canWrite() is an option.

Comment: You can try this but you can have any number of processes writing to the same file.  AFAIK canWrite checks permissions, not whether you can obtain a write lock.

Comment: I will give it a try , but from the documentation of this function , i can feelthat what you are saying is correct.

Comment: "allowed" mean permissioned. It gives no indication that another file is writing to it.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: The modification date wouldn't change for a file that's actively being written to. The modification date is set to the time the file is opened for write, not constantly set while its writing.

Comment: @garlicman if you keep appending to a file, you will see it's modification date change. If you use RandomAccessFile you can use flags to prevent that happening (for optimisation)

Comment: Is that true if the file is still being activity written to? Are you suggesting that using RandomAccessFile to write the file to disk will update the modification date for each flush? (this is a detail I'd like to know)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is, you are reading the file, and you don't get `end of file` token and you want to know when this file will get complete i.e. when you will get `end of file` token.

Now there are 2 options available:

1. You know the process which is downloading the file, in that case it is possible to synchronize with the process. It seems highly unlikely because you may not know about the file. It may be any random file in use-case.
2. You can only do error handling if its not 1st option. probably wait for `eof` token for some `t` time and after timer expiry, again read the size of file, if it has increased, that means read some more bytes and again start the same process of timer. Downside is it might take infinite time, so you must have some mechanism in place to abrupt it any time in between.

There seems no clear cut answer to this question. It totally depends on your use case.
Only option seems checking modification date(as @Peter mentioned) or reading size of file at run time, then handle it according to your use case.